# Can SQL Server Compact be used as both a Source and Destination in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-ce

I'm wondering if SQL Server Compact Edition can be used as both a Source and Destination in an SSIS dataflow.  I know I can setup a SQLMOBILE connection manager, and I've found some information that mentions using it as a Destination, but nothing on using it as a Source.

What I'm looking to do is to transfer data from one SQL Server Compact file to another.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using OLE DB.

The problem is that Sql Server CE is not supported by SSIS User Interface to create OLE DB Connections.

But it's possible to create a OLE DB connection for anything, and then manually change the connection string, using the Property Window. And of course, renaming the connection.

The connection string can be something like:

```
Data Source="D:\path\mydb.sdf";Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;
```

of course, the Provider field must match the SQL Server CE version to be used.

Creating a OLE DB Connection for every sdf database file it' possible to create all OLE DB Sources and Destinations needed to perform the data transfer.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

SQLMOBILE is only available as a destination. If you need to transfer all data, just make a file copy...